# How are tests organised in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

We are currently looking at swapping from selenium to cypress for our automated End to End tests as it looks as if it could stop some of the wait headaches caused by selenium.

As the login time can take a while we use a [OneTimeSetUp] at the start of a test class in NUnit to to do our initial log in then we run our tests from there.

So my question is how are tests organised in cypress? and can we run multiple tests on the same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress uses mocha for the structure of the tests.

describe() block in mocha groups the tests.

it() block tells that this is a test.

e.g.

```
  describe('Login Functionality', function() {

      it('Check Login with Correct Credentials', function() {
           //Your code
      })

     it('Check Login with Incorrect Username', function() {
           //Your code
      })

      it('Check Login with Incorrect Password', function() {
           //Your code
      })


    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is in the official documentation :
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Hooks

Enjoy Cypress!

Sample :

```
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.visit('/users/new')
    cy.get('#first').type('Johnny')
    cy.get('#last').type('Appleseed')
  })

  it('displays form validation', function () {
    cy.get('#first').clear() // clear out first name
    cy.get('form').submit()
    cy.get('#errors').should('contain', 'First name is required')
  })

  it('can submit a valid form', function () {
    cy.get('form').submit()
  })
})
```

Comment: Also, it sounds a bit like RTFM, just in a bit more polite form.